# what is the meaning of " manners and bearing " and "a prepossession in their favour" here?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

what is the meaning of " manners and bearing " and "a prepossession in their favour" here?

> After a return to Rochester, the Fox family made a tour of the Western
>   States, and then paid a second visit to New York, when the same
>   intense public interest was displayed. They had obeyed the spirits'
>   mandate to proclaim these truths to the world, and the new era that
>   had been announced was now ushered in. When one reads the detailed
>   accounts of some of these American sittings, and considers the brain
>   power of the sitters, it is amazing to think that people, blinded by
>   prejudice, should be so credulous as to imagine that it was all the
>   result of deception. At that time was shown moral courage which has
>   been conspicuously lacking since the reactionary forces in science and
>   in religion combined to stifle the new knowledge and to make it
>   dangerous for its professors. Thus in a single sitting in New York in
>   1850 we find that there were gathered round the table the Rev. Dr.
>   Griswold, Fenimore Cooper the novelist, Bancroft the historian, Rev.
>   Dr. Hawks, Dr. J. W. Francis, Dr. Marcy, Willis the Quaker poet,
>   Bryant the poet, Bigelow of The Evening Post, and General Lyman. All
>   of these were satisfied as to the facts, and the account winds up "The
>   **manners and bearing** of the ladies" (I.E. the three Fox sisters) "**are
>   such as to create a prepossession in their favour**." The world since
>   then has dug up much coal and iron; it has erected great structures
>   and it has invented terrible engines of war, but can we say that it
>   has advanced in spiritual knowledge or reverence for the 48 of 188
>   unseen? Under the guidance of materialism the wrong path has been
>   followed, and it becomes increasingly clear that the people must
>   return or perish.

from http://gutenberg.net.au/ebooks03/0301051h.html

Comment: What did you find in the dictionary? Why do you *still* have a problem interpreting these words?

Comment: @FumbleFingers Reinstate Monica  these words are ambiguous for me.

Comment: [**manner**](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/manners) *- a person's outward **bearing**; way of speaking to and treating others*. [**prepossession**](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/prepossession) *- a prejudice or a preconceived idea about something.* Still confused?

Answer (score 2):

"Manners and bearing" means the social behavior and physical presence considered by the surrounding culture to indicate good or bad character.

"Prepossession" means here "an initial opinion."

Moreover, from the language, the word "ladies" is not used here as a synonym for "women," but to mean a "woman of good social standing."

So what the sentence means is this

"The women made a favorable impression because they acted consistently with how women of good social standing are expected to act."

In other words, the sisters appeared respectable.

It is stilted language of another cultural world.

Comment: awesome. that was the exact thing that i need;  a perfect answer.

Comment: does "All of these were satisfied as to the facts" means they were convinced and believed in fox sisters?

Comment: @solesoul yes, that's what it means.

Answer (score 1):

The ideas being expressed here quite old fashioned and from another era, especially the idea that how one behaves can tell you anything useful about someone's true character. So I can understand your confusion.  The language used is also very formal and quite archaic, and nobody really speaks or writes like this today.

***manners*** means polite behaviour, good etiquette

***bearing*** means the way in which one stands or moves, one's posture/deportment.

***prepossession*** means a preconceived opinion, a prejudice, a bias.

In plainer English today we might say something like this instead: "The ladies appeared to be respectable, and so everyone had a good opinion of them".